# Remove words in a string array until it becomes empty

Tags: java, android, string

I have `"help","me","please"` in a String array and I want to remove `"help"` from the array, i.e. after returning it as a string, remove `"me"` after returning it as a string, then remove the last one too, thereby making the string array empty.

I used this

```
public String showCurrentString(){
    EditText ed = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.ed);
    String edText = ed.getText().toString();

    String nn =edText;   
    String[] blure = nn.split(" ");    
    int Index = 1;   

    for(String check : blure){
        if(Arrays.asList(blure).contains(edText)){
            PlaySound(StringName() + ".mp3");
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),check,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

But I don't know how to delete each word after toasting it.

So my main question is on how to delete a words that have been parsed or (that I have already used) from a string array.

Comment: Use an ArrayList. You cannot simply remove elements from an array

Comment: You cannot remove an item from an array. You can however set an array or an item at a specified index to be null once you're done using it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could  delete the first word by doing :

```
nn = nn.substring(nn.indexOf(' '), nn.length);
```

(You can do it multiple time, just check that *nn.trim().length != 0*)

Comment: thanks for the answer but that's no what i mean. I want to maybe like play an audio separately for each word, so i want athe first word to be deleted from the array immediately after the audio plays so that it can parse the second word and play an audio too. Just an example, Thanks for trying to help me.@cricket_007

Comment: Get the word by doing String word = nn.substring(, nn.indexOf(' ')); play the audio, and then use my previous message to delete the word :)

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have following values:

```
edText = "Help Me Please"
blure[0] = "Help"
blure[1] = "Me"
blure[2] = "Please"
```

Then this code should work fine for you:

```
public String showCurrentString(){
    EditText ed = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.ed);
    String edText = ed.getText().toString();

    String nn =edText;   
    List<String> blure = new LinkedList<String>(Arrays.asList(nn.split(" 
")));    

    ListIterator<String> iter = blure.listIterator();
    while(iter.hasNext()) 
    {
        String itemToBeRemoved = iter.next();
        iter.remove();
        System.out.println("Removed "+itemToBeRemoved+"!");
    }
}
```

Comment: You could have edited your previous answer after deleting it

Comment: @cricket_007 hmm.. didn't crossed my mind.. thanks for pointing out.. will keep in mind next time.